# LibGDX - Cannot get texture from FrameBuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, framebuffer

I try to implement some post-processing, so I need to use `FrameBuffer` to collect entire picture and then post-process it with shader. I've found some examples of how to work with `FrameBuffer` in LibGDX([Rendering a 3D model to texture in LibGDX](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/01/21/Rendering-a-3D-model-to-texture-in-LibGDX.aspx)), but it doesn't work. I get black screen. My code snippet:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 0f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0f, -2f, 0f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.ObjLoader loader =new ObjLoader();
    model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("cube/cube.obj"));

    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

 fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
    sb= new SpriteBatch();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
fbo.begin();

    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    modelBatch.begin(cam);

    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);        
    modelBatch.end();

fbo.end();

    //getting texture
    tex = fbo.getColorBufferTexture();

//render texture
  spriteBatch.begin();        
    spriteBatch.draw(tex,0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),  Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

What do I wrong?

***UPDATE***

I got another problem. Look at the pictures bellow:

[image]
[image]

I see this hidden fragment of landscape. I use

```
fb = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
```

But when I try to switch on the depth of `FrameBuffer`, it shows me black screen again:

```
fb = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
```

How to get rid of showing this fragment of landscape and why `FrameBuffer` doesn't work with `depth` parameter?

Comment: Does your code render without the framebuffer?  (If you just render the modelBatch to the screen, does it show something?)

Comment: Sure! If I comment `fbo.begin()` and `fbo.end()`, everything goes perfectly.

Comment: It all looks fine ... the example you linked to does the 3 `Gdx.gl.gl*` before starting the framebuffer (which sort of surprises me, your approach seems better ...).  You might try clearing the framebuffer to a fixed color (e.g., make it all red) to see if its your `modelBatch` that is having problems or if the `spriteBatch` is having problems.

Comment: Hmmm... It's very interesting fact that I tried it with another version of LibGDX and everything went well! Anyway, thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScreenUtils functions to get framebuffer/

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html

```
ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean flipY)
```

Comment: Seems to me it obtains image from default frame buffer. Am I right?